# Fitnesse Browser tests , configuration for pointing to Chrome Binary in Linux

Tags: selenium, fitnesse

I am using Fitnesse to execute a simple test case to login and logout of an application .

The chrome binary is at a different location (not at the default location ).

When I execute the tests , I get an exception .
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error : cannot find Chrome binary .

Is there a way to configure the chrome binary installation location in Fitnesse ?

I am using hsac-fitness-fixtures for web testing using Selenium for this .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share you current configuration for chrome startup (i.e. the wiki page or system properties you use)?

Comment: @DebanjanB its not quite a duplicate as the question is for a specific technology (library wrapping Selenium-Java) not plain Selenium.

Comment: (I can't post answer because question is marked as duplicate so I put it in comment here) via the wiki you can put the configuration in a map variable using something like:
`|script        |map fixture                                       |
|set value  |!-/path/to/chrome/binary-!|for|binary |
|$options= |copy map                                         |`
and then start chrome using:
`|start driver for |chrome|with profile|$options|`

Comment: @FriedHoeben All the community members may not be aware of [tag:fitnesse]. In these cases unless you provide the code trials within the question we can never know how different the usecase is from the dup marked usecase. If OP can update the question with code trials and error stack trace, wecan reopen the question.

Comment: @FriedHoeben : Thanks for your answer . It works . In case we need to run a headless chrome browser , then the binary needs to point to chrome driver location ?